# 'flask' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: bash, flask

I have installed `pip` and `flask` in the directory. After writing flask code in a file, I have run the command `flask run` and get the following error:

> 'flask' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

**Note:** I am in the directory where `pip` and `flask` are installed, and the file is also located here which I want to run.

Comment: Try `python app.py` instead

Comment: Try running `pip show flask`

Comment: Show the full command you use to install `flask`. If you used `--user` option look for flask in `~/.local/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

This may be because you are using virtual environment.

So after activating virtual environment, install flask in the environment and try to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall flask and re-install it using the same commands it worked for me.
Note: I wasn't using any virtual environment.